# Fluent NHibernate One-To-Many Cascade Delete if Many-Side is not referenced anywhere else

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a working solution but would be interested to know if there is a way to achieve this through fluent mapping..

For simplicity, I will use a illustrative example:

```
class Tag {
    string name;
    IList<Book> books;
}

class Book {
    string title;
    Tag primaryTag;
}
```

There is a business case, where Books are deleted and right now, I query the db to check if any other book references the current tag as primary. If not, I delete the book and after that, I delete the tag because it is not used anywhere else. If the tag is stil used, I only delete the book.

Now it's your turn... do you know a way to achieve this using mappings? I tried the following:

```
BookMap : ClassMap<Book> {
    ...
    References(x => x.primaryTag)
    .Cascade.All()  //the collection in TagMap is set to "inverse"
}
```

But not surprisingly, it throws a foreign key constraint error when the tag is used in other books.

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that. NHIbernate is mimicking what you can do in Sql Server config with cascade-deletes. There's no way to go up to a parent and delete "orphans" without using triggers in Sql Server.

There's a way to mimic triggers in NHibernate using "`Interceptors`" - a way to listen for CRUD on specific Entities and then perform actions. But really it's an anti-pattern since you may as well add the same code to the method that removes the Tag (rather in some hidden/obscure approach like the following, which is usefull for cross-cutting concerns such as Auditing).

[This is a really nice article](http://candland.net/2010/01/09/intercepting-nhibernate-to-handle-additional-database-work/) on how to do it (but there's loads out there just google "NHibernate Interceptors").

I'd make sure to use `Session.Delete(entity)` to ensure deleted entities are removed from `Session` (for sanity) rather than